Android sending messages from google messaging app with and without rcs
Basically i am trying to send message that is received from web socket from web app , I am able to send sms when the default sms app is not google messages, but when it is google messages i am unable to send and i am unable to send and getting this (please see the screenshot) , how do i solve this , this is my code for sending sms , and i am taking send_sms permission and i tried by switching off rcs messaging still no luck. Please help
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun sendSMS(phoneNumber: String, message: String) {
        try {
            Log.d("WebT", "SmsService sendSMS :${message} phoneNumber:$phoneNumber")

            val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()

            // Divide the message into parts if necessary
            val parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message)

            // Create PendingIntents for the sent and delivered actions
            val sentIntents = ArrayList<PendingIntent>()
            val deliveredIntents = ArrayList<PendingIntent>()
            for (i in parts.indices) {
                sentIntents.add(
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        context, 0, Intent("SMS_SENT"),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                    )
                )
                deliveredIntents.add(
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        context, 0, Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                    )
                )
            }

            // Send the multipart text message
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(
                phoneNumber,
                null,
                parts,
                sentIntents,
                deliveredIntents
            )
            Log.d("WebT", "SMS sent successfully.")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("WebS", "Error sending SMS", e)
        }
    }

A way to send sms by using google messages
